# Error in initializing a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, syntax

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Initalize(int* p, int n) {
    p = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        p[i] = 5;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int* p = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            Initalize(p, n);
            p[i] += 5;
        }
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the first two values that I get are garbage and the last one is always 10. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The line `Initalize(p, n);` has no effect except leaking some memory.

The line `p[i] += 5;` has undefined behaviour since you are reading from an uninitialized value.

If you removed the line `p = new int[n];` from the `Initialize` function, your code would work, and perhaps even Do What You Expect — depending on your expectations, of course (why are you calling `Initialize` in a loop?).

Answer (score 1):

> the first two values that I get are garbage and the last one is always 10

Actually, 10 is garbage as well: the value of `n` that you pass to `Initialize` is irrelevant, because the function allocates, and leaks, a new array each time that you go through the function.

To fix this program, change `Initialize` to return a new array, and remove initialization to `new int[n]` from the `main`.

```
int *Initalize(int n) {
    int *p = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        p[i] = 5;
    }
    return p;
}
...
int *p = Initalize(n);
cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
p[i] += 5;
cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
delete[] p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Initalize(int* p, int n) {

     p = new int[n];  
     ^
     |
     |
```

This guy here is the culprit. You don't need to reinitialize here. 
 Remove this and things would flow from here.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the array twice. Unless what you want is a two-dimensional array, you should remove this. If you are trying to initialize a two-dimensional array, then `p` in the `main` function should point to an array, not a single integer.

As others pointed out, you're also leaking memory by initializing this and then reassigning to it.